# Open file in Charles from terminal

Tags: charles-proxy

I have started Charles Proxy from terminal like this:

```
/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/MacOS/Charles file.har
```

And now I want to open one more file in Charles from the terminal but I do not want to start another instance of Charles, I want to open the file in the already running instance of Charles.
Is that possible?

Comment: Charles Proxy does not support interactive CLI instructions. The only interactive interface is the Web Interface.

However, you can open your first Charles instance with all required files at once. 

`/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/MacOS/Charles file.har file2.har`

Comment: I solved it by using "open file.har" then I could run "open file2.har" and then it was opened in the same Charles instance.